NP, not NP - Apposition, Coordination or Something Else?
Consider:

I want cake, not candy.

Is "cake, not candy" an apposition of noun phrases, a coordination of noun phrases, or something else?

Apposition: Apposition is "a relationship between two or more words or phrases in which the two units are grammatically parallel and have the same referent." OED. The words "not candy" don't seem like a way of referring to the same thing as "cake". However, if one scopes the referent as being "the thing I want", then perhaps "cake" and "not candy" are operating in parallel to describe the same thing.

Coordination: The word "not" generally is not regarded as a coordinating conjunction. Merriam Webster's categorizes the word "not" as an adverb, and offers the following sense: "used as a function word to stand for the negative of a preceding group of words". That sort of function word sounds much like a conjunctive adverb, but we don't normally see conjunctive adverbs connecting noun phrases as in, "cake, not candy".

Something Else: Could this be a form of coordination reduction? At first glance, there is no conjunction present to effectuate that sort of reduction. Could it be that coordination reduction can be triggered by a conjunctive adverb (e.g., "I want cake, [I do] not [want] candy.")? Or might it be a case of asyndetic coordination triggering a reduction? I cannot find a concise definition of "coordination reduction", but see Petrick, Postal and Rosenbaum (1969).


I suspect there may be no "right" answer and that the more pertinent question is: What is the most useful way of analyzing this sort of construct. I think apposition may be the answer to that question.
EDIT:  Stanford CoreNLP 4.5.5 produces the following constituency parse tree, showing "cake, not candy" as forming a noun phrase with not, as an adverb, participating directly in the noun phrase. I question that parse and reiterate the original question.


You might look into not-stripping, a form of ellipsis:

A particularly frequent type of stripping is not-stripping. The
remnant in the stripped clause is introduced by not and the entire
sentence functions to correct a mistaken assumption in the preceding
context. More often than not, the coordinator is omitted.
Source: Wikipedia — Stripping (linguistics):
Not-stripping

Among the examples offered is this (with ambiguity noted):

Susan gave me some advice, not you. Susan gave me some advice,
Susan gave not you some advice. [you didn’t get advice] Susan gave
me some advice, not you gave me some advice. [you didn’t give advice]

Negative Stripping in English: A Corpus-based
Approach offers this:

The remnant of Not-Stripping can bear a variety of grammatical
functions: (5)   a. John likes swimming, but not Paul.
[Subject]         b. John likes swimming, but
not surfing. [Direct object] . . .

In any case, analyses of the phenomenon abound, so read on.

Thank you. Great suggestions. I'm reading up on them and will circle back.

'stripping and gapping are types of ellipsis, but require coordinate structures. The OP's example is not a coordinate structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics). As in the Wikipedia example: John can play the guitar, and Mary can (play the guitar) also.

@Lambie — Of course it’s a coordinate structure. As noted in the quote above: “More often than not, the coordinator is omitted.” See the examples right below the one you cited: “A particularly frequent type of stripping is not-stripping... e.g.: Sam did it, not Fred [did it]. / Sally is working on Monday, [she is] not [working on Tuesday].

I do not agree with with that. For me: Sam did it, not Fred. = Sam did it, Fred did not do it.  And I don't think that is coordinate. It's declarative versus negative.

@TinfoilHat.  Thanks again for this very helpful answer.  I spent a lot of time digging into Not-Stripping, and I'm now posting a new question in this line of inquiry.  Please let me know what you think.

An apposition requires the apposed word(s) to be right next to the main one: I want cake, not candy. does not meet that criterion. Because of the negative function word not: I want cake, not candy. Implies: I want cake, I do not want candy. The construction is not parallel. One is declarative and the other is an implied negative contruction.

I want cake and candy. Those two are parallel. They are both the object of the verb want.

It was sweetstuff, candy or cake, that made her happy. are appositional.


Merriam Webster:
a
: a grammatical construction in which two or more usually adjacent words, phrases, or clauses (especially nouns or noun equivalents) that have the same referent stand in the same syntactical relation to the rest of a sentence (such as the poet and Burns in "a biography of the poet Burns")

It's the same with It was savouries, not candy or cake, that made her happy. The word not forces us to break it down as a negating construction (of the verb was), rather than apposition.

@FumbleFingers How is your example illustrating something other than what I said?

How is my comment worthy of you calling it into question? I said it's the same.

@FumbleFingers Comments are for adding something new or pointing out something not in an answer.

Thank you.  I see your point.  (But, note that appositive phrases sometimes are setoff by commas and also occur with an expletive "or" introducing them; part of my thinking is that the "not" is playing a similar role to that of the expletive "or".) Carrying your point forward, are you regarding the two independent clauses as forming an asyndetic coordination?

I do wish you'd stop looking for reasons to take issue with me. I think my comment usefully clarifies that even negation of the verb to be works the same as to want in the specific example given by the OP. This is really more of an ELL than an ELU question, and querents at that level don't always see things so clearly. Also please note that the OP  hasn't as yet even upvoted your answer - that's my upvote!

@MatthewRips No, it is a grammar omission. It leaves out what is implied which any native speaker would know...

@Lambie, to be sure about it, this is intended as a question about syntactic parsing. If one were to formulate a constituent parse tree for the example sentence, what would that tree posit regarding the relationship of ", not candy" to the preceding elements of the sentence?

@MatthewRips Generatively, I have already explained it. I parsed the syntax already. One is a declarative I want cake and not x is the implied negative utterrance preceded by a grammar omission [I do] not [want] candy.

@Lambie, I've edited the post to provide more information and some clarification of the nature of the question.

@MatthewRips I really dislike this kind of thing. You already had that tree structure in mind when you asked the question. In fact, you never even mentioned the term tree in your original question. Also, the parse does not show apposition.

@FumbleFingers "This is really more of an ELL than an ELU question"| Well, it came from META by tchrist. Take it up with him.

@MatthewRips: I hadn't read the actual question text carefully until just now. I'm in no doubt the more pertinent question is: What is the most useful way of analyzing this sort of construct? And imho it's more usefully described as parallel negation, with deletion of repeated elements, rather than "negated apposition".

@FumbleFingers I agree but think omission is better than deletion. When I say, I want x, not y. I am in fact not deleting anything. I'm omitting things.

@Lambie: If you think omission means something other than deletion then for all I know you might be right. But the main difference I see is that the "non-deleted" version (I want x, I want not y) doesn't really work today anyway. We need do-support (...I do not want y).

@FumbleFingers That's right and I said that in my answer: [I do] not [want] y. I do and want are omitted because native speaker's fill that in without even realizing it.

@FumbleFingers.  Thanks for the thoughts on this. I'm posting a new question on this same line of inquiry. Please let me know what you think.
